# How to compare 2 arrays value specific with sequence match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare 2 arrays if the value of 2 arrays ever match with specific sequence.

For example:

```
x1=0 v1=3 x2=4 v2=2 
k1=[3,6,9,12,15,18] k2=[6,8,10,12,14,16]
```

will return Yes because 12 is match on array number 3.

```
x1=0 v1=2 x2=5 v2=3 
k1=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14] k2=[5,8,11,14,17,20,23]
```

will return No because despite 14 is match but its not match on specific array sequence.

```
function car(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    let k1 = [];
    let k2 = [];
    for (var i = x1; i <= 10000; i+=v1) {
        k1.push(i) 
    }
    for (var i = x2; i <= 10000; i+=v2) {
        k2.push(i)
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        if (k1[i] === k2[i]) {
            return 'YES'
            break;
        }
        else {console.log('NO')}
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `x1` ,`v1` and so on? where is array number 3. & how 12 is matching?

Comment: does your current function work?

Comment: x1 is starting point , v1 is jump sequence . 12 is matching because its match on specific array sequence k1[3] k2[3]

Comment: my function always produce yes , i already try using k1.indexOf(k2[i]) . because its only compare by value , not by value in specific sequence

Comment: You should stand up from your computer, walk for a bit, come back, and think about whether any loop is necessary at all. And i hope you will not still think they are needed afterwards.

Comment: I think i should just stop caring about this stuff... `const car = (x1, v1, x2, v2) => { if (v2 - v1 === 0) return x1 === x2 ? "YES" : "NO"; let hit = (x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1) - 1; return Number.isInteger(hit) && hit >= 0 ? "YES" : "NO"; }`

Comment: It's checking whether the intersection point(s) of two lines is a positive integer, i guess all those conditions should be necessary. It's 7:40 am and i didn't sleep yet though, so i won't guarantee anything. Ah well, and i don't ever want `NaN` to go around if not absolutely necessary. `NaN` is evil and will cause a lot of headache when it leaks into calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@okky, try with below solution,

Here the problem is with your loop concept. when you go through 1000 value the numbers of elements are not same which matches to your values. I.e K! has 10 value and K2 has 7 then definitely value matching with undefined cause and issue.
Moreover, if value not match then in else part console.log returns no always so this shows output at no in console as many time when value not match. But here he want only display one time value so we must assign its value in global variable. If any case match break loop and assign global variable value as 'YES' Otherwise default value is consider which is no here.

```js
var x1=0, v1=2, x2=5, v2=3, 
k1=[3,6,9,12,15,18], k2=[6,8,10,12,14,16] ;
function car(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    let k1 = [];
    let k2 = [];
    for (var i = x1; i <= 1000; i+=v1) {
        k1.push(i) 
    }
    for (var i = x2; i <= 1000; i+=v2) {
        k2.push(i)
    }
    var totCnt = 0;
    if(k1.length > k2.length)
    {
    totCnt= k2.length;
    }
    else{
      totCnt= k1.length;
    }
    var RetVal = "No";
    for (var i = 0; i < totCnt; i++) {
        if (k1[i] === k2[i]) {
            RetVal ='YES'
            break;
        }
    }
     console.log(RetVal);
}
car(x1, v1, x2, v2);
```

Comment: whats the reson behind downvote this answer? can anyone tell the reason?

Comment: Either explain what the problems in his code are or give a non-terrible solution. You just slap down a terrible solution with "try this".

Comment: @ASDFGerte, let me edit my answer with explanation accordingly.

Comment: My issue with this topic is most of all that i fear OP will walk out of this thinking that creating arrays and iterating over them is an acceptable solution for this problem - it gives me goosebumps.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, thinkl globally i tried with all possibilities as per asked question then only i put my answer here :) BTW, I put my logic in explanation. IF you still have any doubt in understanding , then you are welcome with your query :)

Comment: `car(0, 4, 40000, 2)`  - should be `YES` ... but in your code it is not

Comment: with above loop   i.e car(0, 4, 40000, 2) if you go to 10000, then k1 array get 2501 array element where as k2 get 0 element now here K1.length = 2501 and K2.length = 0. now think which value of K1 match with k2 [where k2 is already doesn't contains any array] ? will you answer me on it?

Comment: @JaromandaX, with array 2 value start from 40000  and reach upto 10000 so alternatively your loop is something like  for (var i = 40000; i <= 10000; i+=2)  now is there any element comes in array 2? If it is then show me.

Comment: @JaromandaX, try yourself, and give the link if my logic breaks at any point i will answer you. you can give your logic bby writing your code in jsfiddle and put its links here :) I am ready to answer

Comment: @JaromandaX, whenever you find logic breaks put your link as well you can answer the question as per your logic too. I am eagerly waiting for your answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171900/discussion-between-priyal-pithadiya-and-jaromanda-x).